# What happens when we add/substract an integer from/tp an address

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

```
int m=44;
int* p= & m;    
int* q = p-1
```

Ok so p is an address how can we substract 1 from it? What will be the output of q and *q

Comment: `*q` is undefined behavior. Erasing your disk as retaliation would be valid according to the standard.

Comment: The output of `q` would be `p - sizeof(int)`. You already know about `*q`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
int m=44;
```

looks like below on 32-bit system

```
       0x103       0x102      0x101       0x100 (lets assume m base address is 0x100)
 ----------------------------------------------
| 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 |0010 1100 |
 ----------------------------------------------
                                               m
MSB                                            LSB
```

When you do like

```
int *p = &m;
```

the pointer variable `p` points to address of `m` like below

```
       0x103       0x102      0x101       0x100 
 ----------------------------------------------
| 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 |0010 1100 |
 ----------------------------------------------
                                               m
                                               |
                                               p <-- points to 0x100
```

And this

```
int* q = p-1;
```

the integer pointer gets assigned with `p-1` which is not valid  as shown below

```
  0x107.................0x104       0x103       0x102      0x101       0x100 
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |   un-initialized memory   | 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 |0010 1100 |
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
                          <--q                                              p
```

so if you tries to do `*q` it tries fetch the data `0x104` onwards which was not reserved for `q` results in **segmentation fault** & cause **undefined behavior**.

*Ok so p is an address how can we substract 1 from it?* you can do `q = p - 1` as by doing so you are *assigning one address* to `q` which it needs but point is it's not valid address, hence when you do `q` it got crashed. For e.g

```
int main(void) {
   int m=44;
   int *p = &m;    
   int* q = p-1;
   printf("%p\n",(void*)q); /* this is valid */
   //printf("%d \n",*q); /* this cause seg fault */
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: According to the standard (and even if it works on most mainstream compilers exactly as you tell) p-1 is already undefined behavior, even without  dereferencing the resulting pointer :-/

Answer (score 1):

The C++ standard explains this in [expr.add]/4:

> When an expression that has integral type is added to or subtracted from a pointer, the result has the type of the pointer operand. If the expression P points to element x[i] of an array object x with n
>   elements, (...)  the expression P -
>   J points to the (possibly-hypothetical) element x[i − j] if 0 ≤ i − j
>   ≤ n; **otherwise, the behavior is undefined**.

So in your case the behavior is undefined since p doesn't point to an array.

*In practice, on most mainstream compilers, q will just point to some memory location `sizeof(int)` bytes before m. But since the standard doesn't tell much about the memory layout, it could be anywhere. Dereferencing q could result in any kind of weird behavior from garbage value to segfault or memory corruption.*

Answer (score 0):

int m=44;

int* p= & m;

int* q = p-1

Here q points to the the block which is before m and its uninitialised.
so q will give address of m-sizeof(int) and *q will give you junk(value bw -(2^32)/2 & (2^32)/2 -1).